# How to return each parameter in JSON by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of words. I am not getting how can I convert each word into json by using JavaScript?

Here is the piece of code that I am using:

```
this.new_testing = [];
      this.newcontent=Contents.split(' ');
      console.log(this.newcontent, 'word count')
      console.log(JSON.stringify({newtesting : this.newcontent}), 'word count json');
      console.log(this.new_testing.push(this.newcontent) , ' all push list')
      console.log(this.new_testing, ' string testing')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sentence = 'there is nothing happening';
words = sentence.split(' ');
wordList = words.map((word,index) => {
    return {
        word,
        color: logicForColor(index, words)
    }

});

function logicForColor(index, words) {
    return index ===0 ? 'RED': index===words.length-1 ? 'BLUE' : '';
}

console.log('WList:', wordList)
```

Outputs

```
0: {word: "there", color: "RED"}
1: {word: "is", color: ""}
2: {word: "nothing", color: ""}
3: {word: "happening", color: "BLUE"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must determine your color of word yourself

```js
var str = "There is nothing happening"; 
var splitted = str.split(" "); 
splitted.forEach(i=>{
  let dataObject: any = {
    word: i,
    color: 'red'
  };

  let dataObjectSpace: any = {
    word: ' ',
    color: 'red'
  };

  this.dataObjectList.push(dataObject);
  this.dataObjectList.push(dataObjectSpace);
});
```